# Python Scrapy - Need a fix for FormRequest used for pagination using AJAX calls - kinda lost here

Tags: python, python-3.x, ajax, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from lxml.html import fromstring
from ..items import PontsItems
from scrapy.http import FormRequest


class Names(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'enseafr'

    download_delay = 5.0
    current_page = 1

    def start_requests(self):

        my_url = 'https://www.ponts.org/annuaire/ajax/loadresult'
        formdata = {'page': str(self.current_page)}
        return [
            FormRequest(my_url, formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse)
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = PontsItems()

        for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="single_desc"]'):
            name = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_libel"]/a/text()').get().strip()
            description = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_details"]/div/text()').get()
            description = fromstring(description).text_content().strip()
            year = item.xpath('./div[@class="single_details"]/div/b/text()').get()

            items['name'] = name
            items['description'] = description
            items['year'] = year
            yield items

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="next"]/@href').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            self.current_page = self.current_page + 1
            formdata = {'page': str(self.current_page)}
            yield FormRequest(my_url, formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse)
```

All it does is print
2020-09-16 00:50:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST [https://www.ponts.org/annuaire/ajax/loadresult>](https://www.ponts.org/annuaire/ajax/loadresult%3E) (referer: None)
2020-09-16 00:50:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

Im kinda lost how to proceed here.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy doesn't support loading javascript. The page you requested doesn't have the form rendered in the response got by scrapy.

If you need to load javascript in your spider, try

- [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium)
- [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)

Comment: Any idea why this just grabs 1st page and while loading to second it closes webdriver? https://paste.tortoisecommunity.com/fidowivupu.py